# Disable Password Hashing while using the Auth package in Laravel 7.x

Tags: laravel, authentication

I want to disable password hashing for a particular use case. I have found a way by overriding attemptLogin method at loginController. However, I want to know if there is another way. Can I disable the hashing driver in hashing file under config?

Comment: I do not think so,

Comment: Is attemptLogin is the only way? @andy

Comment: You could extend the `EloquentUserProvider` and not do the hash check and in this particular use case use this User Provider instead of the default one